# loop throught child's element throw e error

Tags: jquery

So i trying to figure it out but without effort already try find and children...

```js
$("#loop").on('click',function(){
    kid= $("#some123").children();
    for(i in kid){
      console.log($(kid[i]).html())
    }
  })
  $("#loop2").on('click',function(){
    kid= $("#some123").find('li');
    for(i in kid){
      console.log($(kid[i]).html())
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='some123'>Items
  <li draggable='true'>Item 1</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 2</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 3</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 4</li>
</ol>
<div id='loop'>Loop1</div>
<div id='loop2'>Loop2</div>
```

Each time it throw a error and stop my script.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
```

Any idea why i got error?
And how to prevent?

Comment: share the error  details

Comment: Have you done anything to determine what `i` is when the error occurs?

Comment: Use the library `each()` method off of the `children()`.  Don't use the for loop in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a console log to the `i` will show you that it is trying to use non-numbers for the index, which will not have html contents.

```js
$("#loop").on('click',function(){
    kid= $("#some123").children();
    for(i in kid){
      console.log('what is the key? ', i);
      console.log($(kid[i]).html())
    }
  })
  $("#loop2").on('click',function(){
    kid= $("#some123").find('li');
    for(i in kid){
      console.log('what is the key? ', i);
      console.log($(kid[i]).html())
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='some123'>Items
  <li draggable='true'>Item 1</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 2</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 3</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 4</li>
</ol>
<div id='loop'>Loop1</div>
<div id='loop2'>Loop2</div>
```

Rather than using a for loop on a jQuery object, use the library's `each()` method instead.

```js
$("#loop").on('click',function(){
    kid= $("#some123").children();
    
    kid.each(function(index, element){
        console.log($(element).html());
    });
  })
  $("#loop2").on('click',function(){
    kid= $("#some123").find('li');
    
    kid.each(function(index, element){
        console.log($(element).html());
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='some123'>Items
  <li draggable='true'>Item 1</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 2</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 3</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 4</li>
</ol>
<div id='loop'>Loop1</div>
<div id='loop2'>Loop2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you check the object (kid.children()) you will see that there is also a prevObject , this one does not have the html() function.

// here is an updated version

```
$("#loop").on('click',function(){
kid= $("#some123").children();
console.log(kid)
for(i in kid){
  if (kid[i].html)    // <<< check if that element is your li element
    console.log($(kid[i]).html())
}})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the right way to iterate over a jQuery collection since [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is used for iterating over the properties. Use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate and within the callback, you can use `this` to refer the element.

```js
$("#loop").on('click', function() {
  $("#some123").children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html())
  });
})
$("#loop2").on('click', function() {
  $("#some123").find('li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html())
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='some123'>Items
  <li draggable='true'>Item 1</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 2</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 3</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 4</li>
</ol>
<div id='loop'>Loop1</div>
<div id='loop2'>Loop2</div>
```